# Validate query parameters in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate this query URL.

```
one=1&two=2
```

But I also need to allow empty values to both keys and values. So this should be valid as well.

```
one=&two=2
=1&two=2
```

Comment: please, try to share something before you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pattern: \w*=\w+(\&\w*=\w+)*

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*=\\w+(\\&\\w*=\\w+)*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match("=1&two=2&three=345");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    // TODO:
```

### }

updated to match both key/value is empty: \w*=\w*(\&\w*=\w*)*

```
\w* means ZERO OR MORE word character
\w+ means ONE OR MORE word character
\w? means ZERO or ONE word character
```

Comment: Yes for this wo cases it works for me but I also need to allow for two combined so. "one=&=2" should work.

Comment: How does this match one=&... The value part is always non empty. So this is not an correct answer.

Comment: \w*=\w*(\&\w*=\w*)*   -- using this match both key/value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this :

```
String regex = "\\w*=\\d*&\\w*=\\d*";
System.out.println("one=1&two=2".matches(regex));//true
System.out.println("=1&two=2".matches(regex));//true
System.out.println("one=&=2".matches(regex));//true
```

## Ideone demo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if only two parameters are valid. This regex scans for multiple parameters. Parameter name and value could be zero. Is it valid to have an entry without name and without value?

```
\w*=\d*(?:&\w*=\d*)*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VDlEdpahRJRE6g1J)